# How to reduce model size in Pytorch post training

Tags: python, pytorch, quantization

I have created a pytorch model and I want to reduce the model size.
Defining Model Architecture :-

```
import torch
import torch.quantization
import torch.nn as nn
import copy
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import torch.autograd as autograd
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.utils.prune as prune
import torch.nn.functional as F
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time
import codecs
import pickle
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.utils.prune as prune

from config import Config
from loader import *
from utils import *
from model import BiLSTM_CRF

START_TAG = '<START>'
STOP_TAG = '<STOP>'


def init_embedding(input_embedding):
   """
   Initialize embedding
   """
   bias = np.sqrt(3.0 / input_embedding.size(1))
   nn.init.uniform(input_embedding, -bias, bias)


def init_linear(input_linear):
   """
    Initialize linear transformation
   """
   bias = np.sqrt(6.0 / (input_linear.weight.size(0) + input_linear.weight.size(1)))
   nn.init.uniform(input_linear.weight, -bias, bias)
   if input_linear.bias is not None:
       input_linear.bias.data.zero_()


def init_lstm(input_lstm):
   """
   Initialize lstm
   """
   for ind in range(0, input_lstm.num_layers):
       weight = eval('input_lstm.weight_ih_l' + str(ind))
   

       bias = np.sqrt(6.0 / (weight.size(0) / 4 + weight.size(1)))
    

       nn.init.uniform(weight, -bias, bias)

       weight = eval('input_lstm.weight_hh_l' + str(ind))
    

       bias = np.sqrt(6.0 / (weight.size(0) / 4 + weight.size(1)))
   

       nn.init.uniform(weight, -bias, bias)
   if input_lstm.bidirectional:
       for ind in range(0, input_lstm.num_layers):
           weight = eval('input_lstm.weight_ih_l' + str(ind) + '_reverse')
           bias = np.sqrt(6.0 / (weight.size(0) / 4 + weight.size(1)))
           nn.init.uniform(weight, -bias, bias)
           weight = eval('input_lstm.weight_hh_l' + str(ind) + '_reverse')
           bias = np.sqrt(6.0 / (weight.size(0) / 4 + weight.size(1)))
           nn.init.uniform(weight, -bias, bias)

   if input_lstm.bias:
       for ind in range(0, input_lstm.num_layers):
           weight = eval('input_lstm.bias_ih_l' + str(ind))
           weight.data.zero_()
           weight.data[input_lstm.hidden_size: 2 * input_lstm.hidden_size] = 1
           weight = eval('input_lstm.bias_hh_l' + str(ind))
           weight.data.zero_()
           weight.data[input_lstm.hidden_size: 2 * input_lstm.hidden_size] = 1
    if input_lstm.bidirectional:
        for ind in range(0, input_lstm.num_layers):
            weight = eval('input_lstm.bias_ih_l' + str(ind) + '_reverse')
            weight.data.zero_()
            weight.data[input_lstm.hidden_size: 2 * input_lstm.hidden_size] = 1
            weight = eval('input_lstm.bias_hh_l' + str(ind) + '_reverse')
            weight.data.zero_()
            weight.data[input_lstm.hidden_size: 2 * input_lstm.hidden_size] = 1


 def to_scalar(var):
     return var.view(-1).data.tolist()[0]


 def argmax(vec):
    _, idx = torch.max(vec, 1)
    return to_scalar(idx)


 def log_sum_exp(vec):
   # vec 2D: 1 * tagset_size
    max_score = vec[0, argmax(vec)]
    max_score_broadcast = max_score.view(1, -1).expand(1, vec.size()[1])
    return max_score + \
     torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(vec - max_score_broadcast)))


 class BiLSTM_CRF(nn.Module):

   def __init__(self, vocab_size, tag_to_ix, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, char_lstm_dim=25,
             char_to_ix=None, pre_word_embeds=None, char_embedding_dim=25, use_gpu=False,
             n_cap=None, cap_embedding_dim=None, use_crf=True, char_mode='CNN'):
    super(BiLSTM_CRF, self).__init__()
      self.use_gpu = use_gpu
      self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim  #100
      self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim        #200
      self.vocab_size = vocab_size
      self.tag_to_ix = tag_to_ix
      self.n_cap = n_cap
      self.cap_embedding_dim = cap_embedding_dim
      self.use_crf = use_crf
      self.tagset_size = len(tag_to_ix)
      self.out_channels = char_lstm_dim       #25
      self.char_mode = char_mode

      print('char_mode: %s, out_channels: %d, hidden_dim: %d, ' % (char_mode, char_lstm_dim, hidden_dim))

      if self.n_cap and self.cap_embedding_dim:
          self.cap_embeds = nn.Embedding(self.n_cap, self.cap_embedding_dim)
        # print("self.cap_embeds.weight------",self.cap_embeds.weight)
          init_embedding(self.cap_embeds.weight)

      if char_embedding_dim is not None:
          self.char_lstm_dim = char_lstm_dim
          self.char_embeds = nn.Embedding(len(char_to_ix), char_embedding_dim)
        # print("self.char_embeds.weight-------", self.char_embeds.weight)
          init_embedding(self.char_embeds.weight)
          if self.char_mode == 'LSTM':
              self.char_lstm = nn.LSTM(char_embedding_dim, char_lstm_dim, num_layers=1, bidirectional=True)
            init_lstm(self.char_lstm)
        if self.char_mode == 'CNN':
            self.char_cnn3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=self.out_channels, kernel_size=(3, char_embedding_dim), padding=(2,0))

    self.word_embeds = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    if pre_word_embeds is not None:
        self.pre_word_embeds = True
        self.word_embeds.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(pre_word_embeds))
    else:
        self.pre_word_embeds = False

    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
    if self.n_cap and self.cap_embedding_dim:
        if self.char_mode == 'LSTM':
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim+char_lstm_dim*2+cap_embedding_dim, hidden_dim, bidirectional=True)
        if self.char_mode == 'CNN':
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim+self.out_channels+cap_embedding_dim, hidden_dim, bidirectional=True)
    else:
        if self.char_mode == 'LSTM':
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim+char_lstm_dim*2, hidden_dim, bidirectional=True)
        if self.char_mode == 'CNN':
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim+self.out_channels, hidden_dim, bidirectional=True)
    init_lstm(self.lstm)
    self.hw_trans = nn.Linear(self.out_channels, self.out_channels)
    self.hw_gate = nn.Linear(self.out_channels, self.out_channels)
    self.h2_h1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, hidden_dim)
    self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
    self.hidden2tag = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, self.tagset_size)
    init_linear(self.h2_h1)
    init_linear(self.hidden2tag)
    init_linear(self.hw_gate)
    init_linear(self.hw_trans)

    if self.use_crf:
        self.transitions = nn.Parameter(
            torch.zeros(self.tagset_size, self.tagset_size))
        self.transitions.data[tag_to_ix[START_TAG], :] = -10000
        self.transitions.data[:, tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]] = -10000

def _score_sentence(self, feats, tags):
    # tags is ground_truth, a list of ints, length is len(sentence)
    # feats is a 2D tensor, len(sentence) * tagset_size
    r = torch.LongTensor(range(feats.size()[0]))
    if self.use_gpu:
        r = r.cuda()
        pad_start_tags = torch.cat([torch.cuda.LongTensor([self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]]), tags])
        pad_stop_tags = torch.cat([tags, torch.cuda.LongTensor([self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]])])
    else:
        pad_start_tags = torch.cat([torch.LongTensor([self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]]), tags])
        pad_stop_tags = torch.cat([tags, torch.LongTensor([self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]])])

    score = torch.sum(self.transitions[pad_stop_tags, pad_start_tags]) + torch.sum(feats[r, tags])

    return score

def _get_lstm_features(self, sentence, chars2, caps, chars2_length, d):

    if self.char_mode == 'LSTM':
        # self.char_lstm_hidden = self.init_lstm_hidden(dim=self.char_lstm_dim, bidirection=True, batchsize=chars2.size(0))
        chars_embeds = self.char_embeds(chars2).transpose(0, 1)
        packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(chars_embeds, chars2_length)
        lstm_out, _ = self.char_lstm(packed)
        outputs, output_lengths = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(lstm_out)
        outputs = outputs.transpose(0, 1)
        chars_embeds_temp = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(torch.zeros((outputs.size(0), outputs.size(2)))))
        if self.use_gpu:
            chars_embeds_temp = chars_embeds_temp.cuda()
        for i, index in enumerate(output_lengths):
            chars_embeds_temp[i] = torch.cat((outputs[i, index-1, :self.char_lstm_dim], outputs[i, 0, self.char_lstm_dim:]))
        chars_embeds = chars_embeds_temp.clone()
        for i in range(chars_embeds.size(0)):
            chars_embeds[d[i]] = chars_embeds_temp[i]

    if self.char_mode == 'CNN':
        chars_embeds = self.char_embeds(chars2).unsqueeze(1)
        chars_cnn_out3 = self.char_cnn3(chars_embeds)
        chars_embeds = nn.functional.max_pool2d(chars_cnn_out3, kernel_size=(chars_cnn_out3.size(2), 1)).view(chars_cnn_out3.size(0), self.out_channels)

    # t = self.hw_gate(chars_embeds)
    # g = nn.functional.sigmoid(t)
    # h = nn.functional.relu(self.hw_trans(chars_embeds))
    # chars_embeds = g * h + (1 - g) * chars_embeds

    embeds = self.word_embeds(sentence)
    if self.n_cap and self.cap_embedding_dim:
        cap_embedding = self.cap_embeds(caps)

    if self.n_cap and self.cap_embedding_dim:
        embeds = torch.cat((embeds, chars_embeds, cap_embedding), 1)
    else:
        embeds = torch.cat((embeds, chars_embeds), 1)

    embeds = embeds.unsqueeze(1)
    embeds = self.dropout(embeds)
    lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(embeds)
    lstm_out = lstm_out.view(len(sentence), self.hidden_dim*2)
    lstm_out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
    lstm_feats = self.hidden2tag(lstm_out)
    return lstm_feats

def _forward_alg(self, feats):
    # calculate in log domain
    # feats is len(sentence) * tagset_size
    # initialize alpha with a Tensor with values all equal to -10000.
    init_alphas = torch.Tensor(1, self.tagset_size).fill_(-10000.)
    init_alphas[0][self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]] = 0.
    forward_var = autograd.Variable(init_alphas)
    if self.use_gpu:
        forward_var = forward_var.cuda()
    for feat in feats:
        emit_score = feat.view(-1, 1)
        tag_var = forward_var + self.transitions + emit_score
        max_tag_var, _ = torch.max(tag_var, dim=1)
        tag_var = tag_var - max_tag_var.view(-1, 1)
        forward_var = max_tag_var + torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(tag_var), dim=1)).view(1, -1) # ).view(1, -1)
    terminal_var = (forward_var + self.transitions[self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]]).view(1, -1)
    alpha = log_sum_exp(terminal_var)
    # Z(x)
    return alpha

def viterbi_decode(self, feats):
    backpointers = []
    # analogous to forward
    init_vvars = torch.Tensor(1, self.tagset_size).fill_(-10000.)
    init_vvars[0][self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]] = 0
    forward_var = Variable(init_vvars)
    if self.use_gpu:
        forward_var = forward_var.cuda()
    for feat in feats:
        next_tag_var = forward_var.view(1, -1).expand(self.tagset_size, self.tagset_size) + self.transitions
        _, bptrs_t = torch.max(next_tag_var, dim=1)
        bptrs_t = bptrs_t.squeeze().data.cpu().numpy()
        next_tag_var = next_tag_var.data.cpu().numpy()
        viterbivars_t = next_tag_var[range(len(bptrs_t)), bptrs_t]
        viterbivars_t = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(viterbivars_t))
        if self.use_gpu:
            viterbivars_t = viterbivars_t.cuda()
        forward_var = viterbivars_t + feat
        backpointers.append(bptrs_t)

    terminal_var = forward_var + self.transitions[self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]]
    terminal_var.data[self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]] = -10000.
    terminal_var.data[self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]] = -10000.
    best_tag_id = argmax(terminal_var.unsqueeze(0))
    path_score = terminal_var[best_tag_id]
    best_path = [best_tag_id]
    for bptrs_t in reversed(backpointers):
        best_tag_id = bptrs_t[best_tag_id]
        best_path.append(best_tag_id)
    start = best_path.pop()
    assert start == self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]
    best_path.reverse()
    return path_score, best_path

def neg_log_likelihood(self, sentence, tags, chars2, caps, chars2_length, d):
    # sentence, tags is a list of ints
    # features is a 2D tensor, len(sentence) * self.tagset_size
    feats = self._get_lstm_features(sentence, chars2, caps, chars2_length, d)

    if self.use_crf:
        forward_score = self._forward_alg(feats)
        gold_score = self._score_sentence(feats, tags)
        return forward_score - gold_score
    else:
        tags = Variable(tags)
        scores = nn.functional.cross_entropy(feats, tags)
        return scores


def forward(self, sentence, chars, caps, chars2_length, d):
    feats = self._get_lstm_features(sentence, chars, caps, chars2_length, d)
    # viterbi to get tag_seq
    if self.use_crf:
        score, tag_seq = self.viterbi_decode(feats)
    else:
        score, tag_seq = torch.max(feats, 1)
        tag_seq = list(tag_seq.cpu().data)

    return score, tag_seq
```

create Model Instance:-

```
 model_fp32 = BiLSTM_CRF(vocab_size=len(word_to_id),
               tag_to_ix=tag_to_id,
               embedding_dim=parameters['word_dim'],
               hidden_dim=parameters['word_lstm_dim'],
               use_gpu=parameters['use_gpu'],
               char_to_ix=char_to_id,
               pre_word_embeds=word_embeds,
               use_crf=parameters['crf'],
               char_mode=parameters['char_mode'])
```

Apply Quantization

```
 model_int8 = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
     model_fp32,  # the original model
    {nn.LSTM,nn.Linear},  # a set of layers to dynamically quantize
    dtype=torch.qint8)
```

Checking Quantization Results:

```
def print_size_of_model(model, label=""):
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "temp.p")
    size=os.path.getsize("temp.p")
    print("model: ",label,' \t','Size (KB):', size/1e3)
    os.remove('temp.p')
    return size
```

compare the sizes

```
f=print_size_of_model(model_fp32,"model_fp32")
q=print_size_of_model(model_int8,"model_int8")
print("{0:.2f} times smaller".format(f/q))
```

## Results

model:  model_fp32       Size (KB): 806494.996

model:  model_int8       Size (KB): 804532.412
1.00 times smaller

is there any way to reduce the model size significantly??

Comment: What's the `vocab_size` value? Asking because space occupied by `self.embed_dims` is proportional to this value. If `vocab_size` is big, then first target should be to reduce size of this `nn.Embedding`.

Comment: vocab_size is 2009585.

Comment: then `self.word_embeds` occupy space of `vocab_size * embedding_dim * sizeof(float)` bytes, or when `vocab_size` approximately 2 millions and `embedding_dim = 100` something around `2 * 10^6  * 10^2 * 4` bytes or `8 * 10^5` KB. So it's like most of memory is occupied by `self.word_embeds`, and while `nn.Linear` and `nn.LSTM` not even comparable in size to it(as can be seen from Results section), can answer be reformulated like "how to quantize `self.word_embeds`"?

Comment: embedding layer is not supported in dynamic quantization

Comment: But in static it's supported

Comment: how can we apply static one here

Answer (score 0):

Based on *Results* section of question and `vocab_size` of approximately 2 million, it's seems reasonable to quantize attribute `word_embeds`. Expected that quantization of only this module alone will result in significant drop of memory occupation by weights. According to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html) there is no support for dynamic quantization(which is used for nn.Linear and nn.LSTM in snippet above) of `nn.Embedding`(type of `word_embeds`), but static quantization can handle this. Default `qconfig` which is used in some [pytorch examples](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/static_quantization_tutorial.html) seems not working on `nn.Embedding`, but there is a hint in [issue discussion](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/41396#issuecomment-764230203) how to quantize `nn.Embedding`. After training:

```
from torch.quantization.qconfig import float_qparams_weight_only_qconfig

model_fp32.word_embeds.qconfig = float_qparams_weight_only_qconfig
torch.quantization.prepare(model_fp32, inplace=True)
torch.quantization.convert(model_fp32, inplace=True)
```

And after that `word_embeds` in `model_fp32` will be quantized to `torhc.quint8`.

Comment: @lalit-jain if you try this, may you also reprot size of model quantized this way in comment below

Comment: yes this one worked and able to reduce the size to 220Mb. Thank you so much.